# Java servlet doesn't pass response to AJAX jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets, get

I tried to send request with AJAX jQuery to servlet and to display the table with results, but the only thing I see after sending the response is

[image]

So, as we see, the servlet handles the request and forms the response, but it doesn't come back to js after processing the request.

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

        // Get values from form elements
        let x = $('#x').val();
        let y = $('#y').val();
        let r = $('#r').val();

        // Send an AJAX GET request to the servlet
        $.get('ControllerServlet', { val_x: x, val_y: y, val_r: r }, function(result) {
            let res = result.split(", ");
            let now = new Date();
            let newData = { x: x, y: y, r: r, time: now, execution_time: res[0], result: res[1] };
            console.log(x, y, r);
            let newRow = '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + newData.x + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + newData.y + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + newData.r + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + newData.time + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + newData.execution_time + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + newData.result + '</td>' +
                '</tr>';
            $('#result-table tbody').append(newRow);
        });
    });
});
```

And here is my servlet code:

```
@WebServlet("/ControllerServlet")
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        CustomResponseWrapper wrapper = new CustomResponseWrapper(resp);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/AreaCheckServlet").include(req, wrapper);

        String resultString = wrapper.getRes().getResult().toString();
        String queryTimeString = wrapper.getRes().getQueryTime().toString();
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println(queryTimeString + ", " + resultString);
        resp.getWriter().close();
        resp.getWriter().flush();
    }
}
```

I tried to change the browser, rewrite the ajax into fetch api. But nothing helped and it seems that the problem is in my servlet code.

Comment: I think it's CORS Problem. You need CORS Header access-control-allow-origin

Comment: @WladimirDiskowski, can you tell me more about implementation of this technology in my case, please?